# How to write unit test for Spring boot data mongodb excluding Embedded mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

- I need to write unit test for dao layer where i am using spring boot
  with data mongodb.
- I have seen lot of unit test with embedded mongodb where auto
  configuration is used.
- I need to write unit test with actual mongodb not the embedded one.
- MondoTamplate is to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by actual MongoDB? Do you have an instance of MongoDB installed somewhere and you just want to use it?

Comment: yaa not the embedded one

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional `application-test.properties` where you could override the default url and password properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=<your-test-mongodb-host>
spring.data.mongodb.password=<your-test-mongodb-password>
```

and add the following annotation to your dao test classes:

```
@ActiveProfile("test")
```

In this way when the Spring context is started it will look for your "test" profile, which will provide URL and password for properly connecting to you test database. About the dependency to EmbeddedMongo... just remove it from your pom.xml file.